# Error uploading app to TestFlight what do I do to fix it?

Tags: swift, xcode, flutter, dart, webview

[image: This is the error I get while trying to upload]

What do I do? Is there some sort of permission I have to allow to have a web view in my app?

My app has a webview and uses the Flutter web view plugin but I don't get any errors when normally using it. Not sure why I get errors when uploading but don't get any while running the code on a device. Can anyone help or at least point me in the right direction of where to look for a solution?

Here I am trying to upload to App Store Connect for IOS but right before it's done uploading this screen pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this key in your info.plist file.

```
 <key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
    <true/>
```